# How to use "push_back" function vector of Complex struct in boost.interprocess shared memory

Tags: c++, vector, boost, struct, interprocess

Sorry to bother you.
I am writing code to make this code,"http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ab21481b69d87bb" in this question "[Structures and vectors in Boost Shared Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513051/structures-and-vectors-in-boost-shared-memory)", the basis

But, I am stuck in compile error of this line.

```
data.push_back(id);   // 14 line in main function
```

This "data" val is no matching "push_back" function.
This val is declared by "auto&" in this line.

```
auto& data = Shared::locate(smt);   // 10 line in "while(1)" of main function
```

(This locate(smt) function is construct of a complex struct's vector in shared memory )

I assume that "data" is vector or iterator of the complex struct, but there are no way to run this line that I know.

I wonder I was wrong somewhere in this code, but I don't know where is.

Please, help me.

**Note 1**:
line of "data.push_back(id);" is no matching function for call to ‘boost::container::vector, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >, boost::interprocess::allocator, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >, boost::interprocess::segment_manager, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >::push_back(InData&)’
 **candidate**: void boost::container::vector::push_back(const T&) [with T = BasicInData, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >, boost::interprocess::segment_manager, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >]|

**Note 2** :
Now, I try to change to the line below;

```
cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> mat;
cv::VideoCapture vcap(0);

InData id(Shared::alloc<uchar_allocator>);
   // camera open check
if (!vcap.isOpened())
    return -1;
```

But, another compile error occuring "'id' which is of non-class type ".
I feel lack of something. How do i do?

```
//  opencv's lib    
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
//  opencv's lib end
#include <string>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // use for Coliru
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>   // boost/containers/vector.hpp
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>   // boost/containers/string.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 //                                                                    void_allocator;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
//Typedefs of allocators and containers
typedef bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager                       segment_manager_t;
typedef bip::allocator<void, segment_manager_t>  void_allocator;

typedef void_allocator::rebind<uchar>::other                           uchar_allocator;
typedef bip::vector<uchar, uchar_allocator>                                   uchar_vector;



template <typename Alloc = std::allocator<char> >
struct BasicInData {

    public:
        BasicInData(Alloc alloc = {}) : image(alloc)
        { }

        template <typename T>
        BasicInData(double x, int sizeImg, uchar_vector& image, Alloc alloc = {}) :
            x(x), sizeImg(sizeImg), image(alloc)
        { }

        double x = 0;
        int sizeImg = 0;
        uchar_vector image;
};

using InData = BasicInData<>; // just heap allocated

namespace Shared {
    using segment                      = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using segment_manager              = segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using alloc  = bip::allocator<T, segment_manager>;
    template <typename T> using vector = bip::vector<T, alloc<T> >;

    using InData = BasicInData<alloc<char> >; // shared memory version

    vector<InData>& locate(segment& smt) {
        auto* v = smt.find_or_construct<vector<InData> >("InDataVector")(smt.get_segment_manager());
        assert(v);
        return *v;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
        struct timeval tv;
        // there are making no sense 2 line in below, just examine
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
        // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction

        // Create a new segment with given name and size
        struct shm_remove
        {
            shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
            ~shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
        }remover;
        Shared::segment smt(bip::create_only,"MySharedMemory", 65536); // 65536 for coliru
        auto& data = Shared::locate(smt);
        //Shared::alloc bip::alloc_inst (data);
        // Camera Capture 
        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> mat;
        cv::VideoCapture vcap(0);

        InData id;
        // camera open check
        if (!vcap.isOpened())
            return -1;

        while (1) { // while keyboard key push
            vcap >> mat; // camera to mat
            int image_size = mat.total() * mat.elemSize();
            id.sizeImg = image_size;
            id.image.resize(image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            memcpy(&id.image[0], mat.data, image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            // get microsecond by double
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
            id.x = time;
            data.push_back(id);
            if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break; // keyboard pushed
        }
        //Launch child process
        std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child";
        if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
            return 1;

        // check child has destroyed the vector
        if(segment.find<vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first)
            return 1;
        }
    }else{
        // Open the managed segment
        managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

        // Find the vector 
        vector<InData> *myvector = segment.find<vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first;
        // Use vector in reverse order

        vector<InData>::iterator it;

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> im;
        for(it = myvector->begin(); it !=myvector->end(); ++it){
            im.resize(it->sizeImg);
            memcpy(im.data, &imref[0], it->sizeImg);
            cv::imshow("window1", im);
        }

        segment.destroy<vector<InData>>("InDataVector");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first step to debugging an issue involving `auto` outside a `template` is to replace `auto` (or `auto&`) with the type you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you for reply,@David Schmartz. Just a moment,please.

Comment: Now,I replace "auto&" to "Shared::vector<BasicInData>". Complier said " "vector<BasicInData> "cannot convert to "int".  Where is a part of output "int"? I have no idea.

Comment: In which line did it report that error? in the `push_back` call?

Comment: In the line" `auto& data = Shared::locate(smt);`" below "`shm_remove `constructor,and " `auto* v = smt.find_or_construct<vector<InData> >("InDataVector")(smt.get_segment_manager());`" in `namespace Shared`, I don't get it even if These line make rvalue convert to any variable.

Comment: Break the line in which you get the error into multiple lines. For example, change `foo(bar(x));` to `auto j = bar(x); foo(j);` and so on until you can find the smallest piece of code that shows the error.

Comment: @David_Schwartz, That sounds difficult,but I'll give it a try.

Comment: That's hard .Could you give some examples of split in this code?

Comment: Start by assigning `smt.get_segment_manager()` to a variable in a single line. And don't use `auto` -- make sure it's the type you expect it to be!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping.
Finally I can get it.

In this line in main function is

```
InData id;
```

it is changed to

```
Shared::InData id(smt.get_segment_manager());
```

This is full code.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // use for Coliru
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>   // boost/containers/vector.hpp
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>   // boost/containers/string.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 //                                                                    void_allocator;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
//Typedefs of allocators and containers
typedef bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager                       segment_manager_t;
typedef bip::allocator<void, segment_manager_t>  void_allocator;

typedef void_allocator::rebind<uchar>::other                           uchar_allocator;
typedef bip::vector<uchar, uchar_allocator>                                   uchar_vector;



template <typename Alloc = std::allocator<uchar> >
struct BasicInData {

    public:
        BasicInData(Alloc alloc = {}) : image(alloc)
        { }

        template <typename T>
        BasicInData(double x, int sizeImg, uchar_vector& image, Alloc alloc = {}) :
            x(x), sizeImg(sizeImg), image(alloc)
        { }

        double x = 0;
        int sizeImg = 0;
        uchar_vector image;
};

using InData = BasicInData<>; // just heap allocated

namespace Shared {
    using segment                      = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using segment_manager              = segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using alloc  = bip::allocator<T, segment_manager>;
    template <typename T> using vector = bip::vector<T, alloc<T> >;

    using InData = BasicInData<alloc<uchar> >; // shared memory version

    vector<InData>& locate(segment& smt) {
        auto* v = smt.find_or_construct<vector<InData> >("InDataVector")(smt.get_segment_manager());
        assert(v);
        return *v;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
        // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction

        // Create a new segment with given name and size
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        struct shm_remove
        {
            shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
            ~shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
        }remover;
        Shared::segment smt(bip::create_only,"MySharedMemory", 65536); // 10 Kb for coliru
        auto &data = Shared::locate(smt);
        //Shared::alloc bip::alloc_inst (data);

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> mat;
        cv::VideoCapture vcap(0);

        Shared::InData id(smt.get_segment_manager());


        if (!vcap.isOpened())
            return -1;

        while (1) {
            vcap >> mat;
            int image_size = mat.total() * mat.elemSize();
            id.sizeImg = image_size;
            id.image.resize(image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            memcpy(&id.image[0], mat.data, image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            //Launch child process
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
            id.x = time;
            data.push_back(id);
            if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }

        std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child";
        if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
            return 1;

        // check child has destroyed the vector
        if(smt.find<Shared::vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first)
            return 1;

    } else{
        // Open the managed segment
        bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_only, "MySharedMemory");

        // Find the vector using c-string name
        bip::vector<InData> *myvector = segment.find<bip::vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first;
        // Use vector in reverse order

        bip::vector<InData>::iterator it;

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> im;
        for(it = myvector->begin(); it !=myvector->end(); ++it){
            im.resize(it->sizeImg);
            memcpy(im.data, &it->image[0], it->sizeImg);
            cv::imshow("window1", im);
        }

        segment.destroy<bip::vector<InData>>("InDataVector");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this sample work with something other than a VideoCapture()? While making changes the code breaks with. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::bad_alloc'
  what():  boost::interprocess::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest get `BasicInData(const BasicInData &data)` and  `BasicInData &operate =(const BasicInData &data)` function.

Comment: Thank you for reply.Then, Will  I have to create such as function?